# Passing props array to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to pass an array of objects from a parent to a child component as a prop then go map over it and display it in the child component. When I try to map it nothing happens, when I console.log it, it shows my array of objects. What's the difference, what's breaking here?

```
class ClothingBuyingOptions extends Component {

state = {
    size: '',
    color: '',
    showShoppingBag: false,
    items: []
  }

  addItemToBag = () => {
    const { size, color } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      showShoppingBag: true,
      items: [ ...this.state.items, [{ size: size, color: color }]]
    });
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <button
            onClick={this.addItemToBag}>
              Add to Bag
          </button>
          <ShoppingBag items={this.state.items} />  
        </div>
      );
  }
}


class ShoppingBag extends Component {

  render() {
    const items = this.props.items.map((item, index) =>
      <div
        key={index}>
        <p>{item.size}</p>
        <p>{item.color}</p>
      </div>
    )
    console.log(this.props.items)
    return (
      <div className="container">
       {items}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `items` starts as an empty array. When or how is `addItemToBag()` called?

Comment: I have a button that calls it onClick. `<button onClick={this.addItemToBag}>Add to Bag</button>`

Comment: items is an empty. state will be merged, there is no need to  call state with ...this.state.item. You need to setState with the item you want to have in state. And   where is the button? :)

Comment: Sorry, cut a lot out to make it more concise. Added the button back. Not sure what you mean, if I don't call it with the spread operator how do I keep adding to the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're storing an array inside an array, and then trying to access your object properties on an array.

Change this line:

```
items: [ ...this.state.items, [{ size: size, color: color }]]
```

To this:

```
items: [ ...this.state.items, { size: size, color: color }]
```

The way your state is being constructed with your code is like this:

```
items: [
 [ { size: '', color: ''} ],
 [ { size: '', color: ''} ]
]
```

And you want it to be this:

```
items: [
 { size: '', color: ''},
 { size: '', color: ''}
]
```

Also, since your object keys and values are the same, you can define your object as `{size, color}`, which is the same as `{size: size, color: color}`

Comment: Thank you, that was it and very helpful.